# Using index.html for Hugo file serving

Tags: server, hugo

I am able to serve a Hugo web site on port 1313.  I don't have access to port 80, but I can write index.html and the public_html directory.  How do I configure Hugo so that my site is served from mydomain.com instead of mydomain.com:1313?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to run as a server. Build the site by just running command "***HUGO***". This will generate a *public* or *output* folder. Copy the contents of the public folder and past to the publich_html directory of your hosting. This will work like normal HTML pages.

For the development purpose only we need to use as "***HUGO SERVER***"